# How to publish ASP.NET MVC app from Visual Studio to Server 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, visual-studio, web-deployment

We're building an ASP.NET MVC 5 app in Visual Studio 2015. Thus far, we've been publishing to Windows Server 2008 R2. Someone set up the server but never documented the steps. Now, we have a new Windows 2012 Server and need to set it up to allow one-click publish from Visual Studio to the server.

One-click means being able to right-click the project > Publish > choose profile > publish. It writes the app to the server and then opens the site in the browser.

I've looked at the following articles/posts:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later
- https://serverfault.com/questions/487744/web-deploy-on-windows-server-2012
- http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-install-webdeploy-on-windows-server-2012/

But I'm not sure if Web Deploy is what enables the one-click publish from Visual Studio. Read also that Web Management Service has to be running on the server for all this to work. In other words, I don't even know where to begin!

I'd also like to change the default publish port from 8172 to something like 8443. Is that possible? Does Visual Studio allow that?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.